# GeoToolsSpatialRDDProvider (GeoMesa Spark) extremely inefficient

Tags: apache-spark, geomesa

I am trying to read roughly 2.5M rows from a GeoPackage file using GeoMesa's Spark integration. Since there is no custom SpatialRDD implemented for this `DataStore`, I have to use the `GeoToolsSpatialRDDProvider`. For layers with 10k-100k rows, this works perfectly. However, when I try to load layers with millions of rows, the process never finishes.

I looked into the [implementation](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/2d0f56a55ca4319eff842ca85a6b61305632acfc/geomesa-gt/geomesa-gt-spark/src/main/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/geotools/spark/GeoToolsSpatialRDDProvider.scala#L46) of `GeoToolsSpatialRDDProvider` and the issue seems to be that the `rdd` method in it tries to convert the `FeatureReader` iterator to a `List` so that it can be parallelised by the `SparkContext`, but the conversion never terminates and Spark keeps printing a lot of warnings (mainly Futures timing out), until eventually it runs out of memory.

Is there a way of making this more efficient without increasing Spark driver memory?

Answer (score 0):

The `GeoToolsSpatialRDDProvider` was intended as an easy way to get data into Spark, but it is not meant for heavy workloads. I don't believe Spark has any way to parallelize data into a Spark cluster from a single thread without loading it into memory first. As a work-around, you could load your data in batches that are small enough to complete, and then take a union of the resulting RDDs.